# How to pull out hard drive on Lenovo T430 laptops?

Tags: hard-drive, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I would like to pull out my hard drive, it looks like this:

[image]

I found in some videos that there should be a pull-out cable (like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EtLMEZex70&t=44s) but I do not have such a cable.

What can I do now?

Comment: It's not a *"pull-out cable"*, but a pull tab that would be attached to the [HDD caddy](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/COAAAOSwhmNcrvtj/s-l1600.jpg).  Your HDD seems to be missing the caddy as well as the soft guide rails.  Your HDD can rattle within its cavity, and therefore is extra vulnerable to movement and shock.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a strip of scotch tap / fabric tape / duct tape to the left and right side of the drive (where the rubber rails would be) and gently pull it out.

Here's another photo:

[image: thinkpad caddy]

Answer (score 0):

There's a divot, or dimple, in the leading edge of the drive. Using a pair of small electrician's pliers, grasp the drive there, using no more force than necessary, and pull it out. You may find the [hardware manual](https://thinkpads.com/support/hmm/hmm_pdf/t430_t430i_hmm_en_0b48304_03.pdf) helpful.